# Is it ok to return a reference of a function scope static variable?

Tags: c, embedded

I wanted to know if that has any ill effects under any circumsatnce.

For ex:

```
Ex1:
void* func1()
{
   void* p_ref = NULL;
   //function scope static variable
   static int var1 = 2;
   p_ref = &var1;
   return p_ref;
}
Ex2:

//file scope static variable
static int var2 = 2;

void* func2()
{
   void* p_ref = NULL;
   var2 = 3;
   p_ref = &var2;
   return p_ref;
}
```

So in the above two cases what is the difference apart from the fact that var1 is function scope and var2 is file scope.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is any difference. They're both global variables, it's just that the name of the first one is only visible inside the scope of the function func1.

Comment: One difference between your two functions is that func2 will set the value of the global variable var2 to 3 every time it is called. Whereas func1 will not change the value of var1.

Comment: I would say that they both have static storage duration which does not mean they both are global variables. Globals are declared outside functions.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially no difference apart from scope.

Hence, local variable is preferable if that pointer
is going to be the only way to access the variable.

Comment: Note, though, that function-level static variables tend to make your code non-reentrant, if you rely on (or especially if you change) the value outside the function.  Don't do it if you value your sanity.

Comment: @cHao: In this respect too, they are no different to global-scope static variables.

Comment: @caf: Right...globals of any type will likely cause reentrancy issues.   Function-level statics are particularly insidious, though, partly because at first glance they don't *look* like globals -- even though in every sense that really matters, they are.